# Angular 2 unable to load images when ng build dist folder( renamed to myapp) is deployed in tomcat webapp folder

Tags: apache, angular, tomcat, angular-directive

I'm passing the relative path, and using the following command to build!

```
ng build --prod --aot --base-href /myapp/
```

I get the below error 404 Resource not found error.

```
bkgraph.jpeg:1 GET http://localhost:8081/assets/bkgraph.jpeg 404 ()


  <img src="../../assets/bkgraph.jpeg" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
```

Answer (score 1):

To load the images you need to remove the `'../../'` before the assets. it should be `<img src="assets/bkgraph.jpeg" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">` like this in the tomcat server.

Comment: Yeah i tried several combinations ./assets and assets/bkgraph works! but why? Is it because earlier the base-href was / now it's my app?

Comment: yes.with that only. you need to change the base href from <base href="/"> to <base href="."> or simply use like this <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

Comment: actually my base-href is /my-app/ so assets will be in /myapp/assets right?

Comment: yes, here <base href="."> , here dot means  my-app path only no need to specify manually